# How can I make an animated view be a consistent distance from the bottom of the screen on all devices?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewanimation

I'm working on a feature that will animate a `UIView` up from the bottom of the screen to tell the user their data was saved. However, it doesn't appear in the same place on an iPhone 11 Pro Max as it does on an iPhone X.

iPhone 11 Pro Max (this is what I want it to look like):

[image]

but on an iPhone X:

[image]

I should probably note that I created the view on the storyboard and have an `@IBOutlet` connected to it. On the storyboard, it's positioned where you see it in the top screenshot. I did not place any constraints on it. The rest is done in code.

The code to animate is very simple:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    savedView.center.y += view.bounds.height // start with it off the screen 
    savedView.center.x = (view.bounds.width / 2)

}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    // animate it onto the screen
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.6, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
        self.savedView.center.y -= self.view.bounds.height <-- the problem must be here

    }, completion: nil)

}
```

I thought it might be due to different device size classes but all iPhones are 'regular' height so I don't think that's it.

How can I get this view to end up in the same position (relative to the bottom of the screen) on all devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out.

The problem was that the view's initial `center.y` position was starting off at 814 *based on its position in the storyboard*. So it looked good on the storyboard which I'm viewing as an iPhone 11 Pro but, when run on other device simulators with different dimensions, the math didn't work anymore.

The solution was to set the `center.y` position based on the `view.bounds.height` giving it a consistent starting position on any device:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    savedView.center.y = (view.bounds.height - 60) // position the view 60 pixels bottom
    savedView.center.x = (view.bounds.width / 2) // center it horizontally
    savedView.center.y += view.bounds.height // move it outside the visible bounds

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to place your views in the *same place* across all devices is a must to have constraints set up. So that, the system is able to show your views correctly.

So to achieve a bottom-centered attached behavior for your view, you need to set up a constraint to the **safe-area bottom**, a constraint called **centered-horizontally**, **width** and **height**, assuming that this view is the only component on screen. If it is not, then there must be a **top constraint** for the view with the component in the top of it.

Hope this helps, at least to give you an idea.

[Constraints reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJbng.png)

Comment: But I’m animating the view from its position off screen to its final position as you see in the first screenshot. I don’t think adding those constraints will work

Comment: Oh, Ok. I misunderstood your question. Anyway, you should always use constraints for a real world app. The solution you found could be done actually with constraints. So you don't have to worry about the .center and bounds calculations.